# Обмен данными между Android клиентом и Java сервером

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, как сейчас, в 2020-м, правильно построить коммуникацию между клиентом и сервером?
Я использую java.net.Socket, но как по мне, это не лучшее решение.

Comment: Имеется введу, какие технологии/библиотеки использовать.

Comment: Сервер - консольное ПО

Answer (score 1):

однозначного рецепта нет.

все зависит от требований, вот *приблизительный* путеводитель:

- если скорость не критична, структуры и объемы не большие лучше всего подойдет старый добрый REST
- если модель слишком сложная и/или запросы сильно варьируются (настолько, что пере-/недо-грузка становится ощутимой), то можно посмотреть на GraphQL
- если же скорость критична, то имеет смысл рассмотреть gRPC
- если стандартные протоколы не подходят, можно попробовать и свой, на основе WebSocket, ну или если нужен полный контроль, то на TCP или UDP, если конечно у Вас есть столько времени на разработку и отладку :)

Answer (score 0):

По разному можно. Есть много способов от самых простых до самых сложных. Можно воспользоваться уже готовым протоколом. Например:

- MQTT
- AMQP
- WebSockets
- и т.д.

Можно пойти по сложному пути — написать свой протокол. [Список протоколов по OSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_network_protocols_(OSI_model)#Layer_7_(Application_Layer)) . Есть такие вещи типа P2P. Так что исчерпывающий ответ дать нельзя, вот только общие идеи. Есть куда копать ;)